# Count consecutive sublists with same length

Tags: haskell

I am trying to count the elements of a list that are the same length for n and n+1.

I wrote this code:

```
countSec :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
countSec (x:xs) = if (length x)==(length (head xs)) 
    then 1+(countSec xs) 
    else (countSec xs)
countSec [] = 0
```

As you may guess, it's not working. In fact, as a output I get "*** Exception: Prelude.head: empty list"

`countSec [[1,2][1,2],[2],[3,5],[2],[5]]` should return 2 (the first two and the last two sublists have the same length).

Any clue on what the problem can be?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't handle the case where there is only one element in the list of lists, so you run into an error as soon as you call `head` on `xs`, which will be `[]`, since there's no first element of an empty list :)

You can use pattern matching to fix this:

```
countSec :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
countSec [] = 0
countSec [_] = 0
countSec (x : xs@(y:_))
  | length x == length y = 1 + countSec xs
  | otherwise            = countSec xs
```

I used pattern matching to match two elements of the list at a time. This is just like `x:(y:_)` (patterns can nest), except that we also give the name `xs` to the thing we matched to `y:_`; so we have

```
             xs
x      y _____\_____
 \      \           \
  [1] : ([2, 3] : ...)
```

`x` is the first element of the list, `y` is the second, and `xs` is the list after the first element. We could just match `(x:y:xs)` instead and use `countSec (y:xs)` to recurse, but this would use up more memory and is more error-prone.

The `_` in a pattern means that we don't care about the value at that position, and so don't want to give it a name; it's a wildcard that matches everything.

As a minor stylistic note, I also converted your `if` expression into a guard; these are basically just if expressions at the level of a function clause.

You should avoid using partial<sup>1</sup> functions like `head` when pattern matching would work because of things like this — they hide errors and make code harder to read. I also suggest giving the `-Wall` flag to GHC; if you wrote `countSec` as I did but forgot the zero or one-element case, GHC would warn you about it:

```
Warning: Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
         In an equation for `countSec': Patterns not matched: [_]
```

<sup>1</sup> A function not defined for all its inputs; for instance, `head` and `tail` are not defined on `[]`, and division is not defined when the divisor is 0.

Comment: @LukeMorgan: Sorry, my previous answer had an incorrect algorithm. I've fixed it now.

Comment: On a minor note, this code (as well as the original) calculates the length of each sub-list twice. It might make sense to move the `length` calls out of the function, and do `map length` on the input to only calculate the lengths once.

Comment: @hammar: How about `countSec = sum . ap (zipWith (fromEnum .: (==))) (drop 1) . map length`? :)

Comment: ...or even `sum . map (subtract 1 . length) . group . map length`... OK, I'll stop now :)

Answer (score 3):

A different approach that calculates the length of each list only once,

```
countSec :: [[a]] -> Integer
countSec xss = genericLength . filter id $ zipWith (==) ls (tail ls)
  where
    ls = map length xss
```

The use of the partial function `tail` is perfectly safe here, because the case where it would raise an error is caught by the shortcutting of `zipWith`.

Answer (score 2):

The tail part of your list, the `xs` will be `[]` when you reach the end of the list, and `head` will result in an error.

However, the general answer to this kind of question is *"never use  `head`. Use pattern matching"*. This will instantly show what is wrong in your program:

```
countSec :: [[Integer]] -> Integer
countSec (x:y:xs) = if (length x)==(length y) 
    then 1+(countSec (y:xs)) 
    else (countSec (y:xs))
countSec (x:[]) = ??  
countSec [] = 0
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that before but I guess I made some other mistake. It's working perfectly now!

Answer (score 1):

There are some builtins you can use:

```
import Data.Function (on)
import Data.List (groupBy)

countSec = length . head . groupBy ((==) `on` length)
```